# ¿Cómo guardar favoritos con cookies de una lista de publicaciones en php con mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

Tengo una web en donde se muestran múltiples artículos, algo así como pinterest. Le puse un botón de "Guardar" a cada artículo, con ajax hice de que cuando le den click cambie su estado de "0" a "1", cero es nulo, y uno "guardado", pero me gustaría que también se relacione con el artículo, y se guarde en las cookies, luego hacer otra vista en donde se impriman esos artículos guardados.

Tendrán alguna recomendación? O hay otro camino?

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar usando javascript. Guardas en cookie el id del producto guardado como llave y como valor '1'.

```
document.cookie = "id_" + "{id_producto_clickeado} = 1";
```